# Eclipse Project import Error

Tags: eclipse, compilation, project, android-appcompat

I formatted my Laptop, and re-installed the Eclipse..
Now when I import my projects I have alot of errors, but when I create a new project it works well,..
I spent a week searching in Google and trying but nothing.. So I thought this is the best place, and here are alot of smart people who can help me, so I decided to ask you... 
How can I reslove this error ?

Here is the link of vdieo :  [Click Here to watch video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHgn-scvyMg)

```
    [2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency    list,
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] Versions found are:
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] Path: D:\tst\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika]  Length: 987314
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika]  SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] Path: D:\tst\Matematika\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika]  Length: 758727
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika]  SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-06 22:11:51 - Matematika] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] Versions found are:
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] Path: D:\tst\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika]  Length: 987314
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika]  SHA-1: 9b6a9a9078af571732159b904ad423b03b7cc786
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] Path: D:\tst\Matematika\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika]  Length: 758727
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika]  SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-11-06 22:11:52 - Matematika] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:56 - Matematika] 
Continues still ......
```

One Other Procject this error :

```
2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] 
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity] D:\tst\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-11-06 22:11:57 - MyActivity]
```

[image: And imported Appcompat]

IDK, I am so confused.. I can't find the answer....
When I close and reopen the Eclipse I got this :

[image]

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.ResourceManagerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PreCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Error instantiating builder 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder'.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (429).
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing libraries... try the following:

1.Check .classpath file in your project folder. You might have a reference there. OR
2.Close and re-open the project without closing eclipse, this might rebuild Eclipse resource cache. OR
3.Re-import your project into a clean workspace.

Comment: 1. Where is it and how ? I'm newbie... :( I'm student, and I'm trying to learn ...
 2. I Closed and reopned, but there are alot of errors...
 3. I imported my projects in alot of wokrspaces, but always the same, errorss... I downloaded a sample project from Google there are errors, tried my projects that worked before format there are errors, but I created new project that works great...

Comment: Well dig into it partner that's part of the learning process. I would suggest not looking for direct answers but for pointers and process explanations you'll learn way more this way. I made my thesis in eclipse (android app) and it was a hustle. The thing i commented I found in my notes.

Comment: We don't learn that in school... I training it by myself... In school we learn C#... But I love android programming..